# SFSpeechRecognizer not handling contextual strings properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sirikit, sfspeechrecognizer

`SFSpeechRecognizer` is very inaccurate for my use case. I have tried setting `contextual` strings as I have an array of words against which to match with. But it is still not able to do so. Do I need any other configuration?

I am using sample project provided by Apple with only this change:

```
recognitionRequest.contextualStrings = @[@"iron man", @"metal", @"stark", @"superhero", @"boyfriend", @"pepper", @"arrogant", @"stylish"];
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this

Comment: No. Went with google speech api.

Comment: Actually I added the same context using swift it began to work normally.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that `contextualStrings` are only for adding words, that presumably aren't already there, to the dictionary.

**For example :** `rare/strange` words like `"Expecto Patronum"` or `"Fuddle duddle"`

See more in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest)